# Importing large volume of dummy data into pgAdmin 4 by csv - Failed (exit code:1)

Tags: csv, postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to upload a large amount of dummy data into my pgadmin tables. I was able to use a csv for the smaller tables however I have a larger spreadsheet of data that includes descriptions (with punctuation marks like {'`, which could be causing the upload problem).

I am getting the below error message but I am unable to figure out what it means. I have went through the large bodies of text to remove any marks I think may have been causing it but I am still getting the same error.

Is there a better way to do this as the import tool seems to have a lot of bugs?

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\pgAdmin 4\\v4\\runtime\\psql.exe" --command " "\\copy public.\"marineLifes\" (\"marineLifeID\", \"marineTypeID\", \"marineName\", \"marineDescription\") FROM 'C:/Users/JAMESG~1/Desktop/MARINE~1.CSV' CSV QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE '''';""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [proper CSV file](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000323.shtml), with header row matching fields in existing table, you can import it this way:

1. Open your CSV file in text editor
2. Add this line as first line in file, just above header:

```
COPY public."marineLifes" FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER ON)
```

3. Add this line (consisting only of COPY terminator) as the last line, just after last row:

```
\.
```

4. Save the file as `tmp.sql`.
5. Run the file with `psql`:

```
C:\...\psql.exe -f C:\...\tmp.sql
```